# Finding closest point by comparing two data frames in R

Tags: r, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a set of two data frames in R

```
    First:    
site_no <- c("02110500","02110550", "02110701" , "02110704", "02110760", "02110777", "021108044", "02110815")
lat_coor <- c(33.91267, 33.85083, 33.86100, 33.83295, 33.74073, 33.85156, 33.65017, 33.44461)
long_coor <- c(-78.71502, -78.89722, -79.04115, -79.04365, -78.86669, -78.65585, -79.12310, -79.17393)
AllStations <- data.frame(site_no, lat_coor, long_coor)


    Second:
station <- c("USGS-02146110","USGS-02146110","USGS-02146110","USGS-02146110","USGS-02146110","USGS-021473426","USGS-021473426","USGS-021473426")
latitude <- c(34.88928, 34.85651, 34.85651, 34.85651, 34.71679, 34.24320, 34.80012, 34.80012)
longitude <- c(-81.06869, -82.22622, -82.22622, -82.22622, -82.17372, -81.31954, -82.36512, -82.36512)
ContaminantStations <- data.frame(station, latitude, longitude)
```

My data sets are a lot longer but for the purpose of this question I think this should be enough.

What I would like is to find all the stations from the first data frame (AllStations) that are inside a radius of the points in the second data frame (ContaminantStations) and append them into a new data frame (only the ones from AllStations), I need to extract the station with all its information. I've tried some logical but none of them work or make sense. I also try with RANN:nn2 but that only gives me the count.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *"I've tried some"* ... what have you tried? It is often better to help with code you're familiar with than starting from scratch.

Comment: What happens when it is within the radius of multiple contaminant stations?

Comment: I should then select the closest one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to iterate over each within `AllStations` and return the nearest of the `ContaminantStations` that is within a radius.

```r
func <- function(stations, constations, radius = 250000) {
  if (!NROW(stations) || !NROW(constations)) return()
  if (length(radius) == 1 && NROW(constations) > 1) {
    radius <- rep(radius, NROW(constations))
  } else if (length(radius) != NROW(constations)) {
    stop("'radius' must be length 1 or the same as the number of rows in 'constations'")
  }
  out <- integer(NROW(stations))
  for (i in seq_len(NROW(stations))) {
    dists <- geosphere::distHaversine(stations[i,], constations)
    out[i] <- if (any(dists <= radius)) which.min(dists) else 0L
  }
  return(out)
}
```

This returns a integer vector, indicating the contaminant station that is closest. If none are within the radius, then it returns `0`. This is safely used as a row-index on the original frame.

Each argument must include only two columns, with the first column being longitude. (I make no assumptions of the column names in the function.) `radius` is in meters, consistent with the `geosphere` package assumptions.

```r
ind <- func(AllStations[,c("long_coor", "lat_coor")], ContaminantStations[,c("longitude", "latitude")],
            radius = 230000)
ind
# [1] 0 6 6 6 0 0 6 6
```

These are indices on the `ContaminantStations` rows, where non-zero means that that contaminant station is the closest to the specific row of `AllStations`.

We can identify which contaminant station is closest with this (there are many ways to do this, including tidyverse and other techniques ... this is just a start).

```r
AllStations$ClosestContaminantStation <- NA_character_
AllStations$ClosestContaminantStation[ind > 0] <- ContaminantStations$station[ind]
AllStations
#     site_no lat_coor long_coor ClosestContaminantStation
# 1  02110500 33.91267 -78.71502                      <NA>
# 2  02110550 33.85083 -78.89722            USGS-021473426
# 3  02110701 33.86100 -79.04115            USGS-021473426
# 4  02110704 33.83295 -79.04365            USGS-021473426
# 5  02110760 33.74073 -78.86669                      <NA>
# 6  02110777 33.85156 -78.65585                      <NA>
# 7 021108044 33.65017 -79.12310            USGS-021473426
# 8  02110815 33.44461 -79.17393            USGS-021473426
```

A vis of your data for perspective:

[image: ggplot of station locations]

---

An alternative to this approach would be to return the distance and index of the closest contaminant station, regardless of the radius, allowing you to filter later.

```r
func2 <- function(stations, constations, radius = 250000) {
  if (!NROW(stations) || !NROW(constations)) return()
  if (length(radius) == 1 && NROW(constations) > 1) {
    radius <- rep(radius, NROW(constations))
  } else if (length(radius) != NROW(constations)) {
    stop("'radius' must be length 1 or the same as the number of rows in 'constations'")
  }
  out <- data.frame(ind = integer(NROW(stations)), dist = numeric(NROW(stations)))
  for (i in seq_len(NROW(stations))) {
    dists <- geosphere::distHaversine(stations[i,], constations)
    out$ind[i] <- which.min(dists)
    out$dist[i] <- min(dists)
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Demonstration, including bringing the contaminant station into the same frame.

```r
AllStations2 <- cbind(
  AllStations,
  func2(AllStations[,c("long_coor", "lat_coor")], ContaminantStations[,c("longitude", "latitude")])
)
AllStations2
#     site_no lat_coor long_coor ind     dist
# 1  02110500 33.91267 -78.71502   1 241971.5
# 2  02110550 33.85083 -78.89722   6 227650.6
# 3  02110701 33.86100 -79.04115   6 214397.8
# 4  02110704 33.83295 -79.04365   6 214847.7
# 5  02110760 33.74073 -78.86669   6 233190.8
# 6  02110777 33.85156 -78.65585   6 249519.7
# 7 021108044 33.65017 -79.12310   6 213299.3
# 8  02110815 33.44461 -79.17393   6 217378.9
AllStations3 <- cbind(
  AllStations2,
  ContaminantStations[AllStations2$ind,]
)
AllStations3
#       site_no lat_coor long_coor ind     dist        station latitude longitude
# 1    02110500 33.91267 -78.71502   1 241971.5  USGS-02146110 34.88928 -81.06869
# 6    02110550 33.85083 -78.89722   6 227650.6 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.1  02110701 33.86100 -79.04115   6 214397.8 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.2  02110704 33.83295 -79.04365   6 214847.7 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.3  02110760 33.74073 -78.86669   6 233190.8 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.4  02110777 33.85156 -78.65585   6 249519.7 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.5 021108044 33.65017 -79.12310   6 213299.3 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
# 6.6  02110815 33.44461 -79.17393   6 217378.9 USGS-021473426 34.24320 -81.31954
```

From here, you can choose your radius at will:

```r
subset(AllStations3, dist < 230000)
#       site_no lat_coor long_coor ind     dist        station latitude longitude
# 6    02110550 33.85083 -78.89722   6 227650.6 USGS-021473426  34.2432 -81.31954
# 6.1  02110701 33.86100 -79.04115   6 214397.8 USGS-021473426  34.2432 -81.31954
# 6.2  02110704 33.83295 -79.04365   6 214847.7 USGS-021473426  34.2432 -81.31954
# 6.5 021108044 33.65017 -79.12310   6 213299.3 USGS-021473426  34.2432 -81.31954
# 6.6  02110815 33.44461 -79.17393   6 217378.9 USGS-021473426  34.2432 -81.31954
```